# Can a QML DelayButton's flashing be programmatically turned off?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquickextras

I have a [`DelayButton`](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickEnterpriseControls/qml-qtquick-enterprise-controls-delaybutton.html) that I would like to stop flashing (after it's been pressed) when the operation triggered by the button is completed.

However, it appears that none of the properties `DelayButton` are writeable. Is there a way to stop the flashing, or must it always flash until the user presses the button again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DelayButton` is a subclass of the `Button`. The flashing state is actually linked to the `checked` property of the `Button`, so the `button.checked = false` will help.

You can always look into the source code: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/extras/DelayButton.qml

Comment: Perfect. Since the flashing is specific to `DelayButton`, I didn't think to check whether it's affected by any of the properties in the base class. Thanks.